# Android Location services

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to create a database of gps coordinates by walking some trails and periodically storing coordinates.  What would be the best way to get gps coordinates quickly sent and stored on the phone in an array of some sort so I could later access the coordinates.  I need to be able to save them on the phone and then get them back to the computer. Any tips will be helpful.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a great page on acquiring location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) and I'd suggest you store the locations received in a [Sqlite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), which means the location data will persist between each time you run the app, which seems like what you need.

As each location comes in, you can store them in the database, and from there it's easy to handle them, e.g. pass them on. Not sure what you mean by "get them back to the computer, as you don't say why or in what format.

Comment: I need to collect all of the GPS points and store them in some array in my program so that I can use them plot trail overlays and compare the locations saved in the program to the users current location.

Comment: Using an array alone is not a good solution, as parts of your app may be pushed out of memory (when the user goes to another app) so you need something more stable. I'd suggest considering pushing the points of data to the SQL database, and then pull them out through content provider and into your array for processing.